# How can I bind poweroff with git push?

Tags: ubuntu, zsh

I live in a remote location and internet is scarce.

Whenever i do `sudo poweroff` I want it to try `git push` also. And if push fails, abort shutdown, otherwise continue with shutdown.

How can I achieve this without modifying the binary?

Comment: `git push && sudo poweroff`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a few alternatives on the same theme. All creates a command called `gitoff` that will perform a `git push` followed by `sudo shutdown -h now` if the push succeeded.

```
alias gitoff='git push && sudo shutdown -h now'

gitoff () {
    git push && sudo shutdown -h now
}

gitoff () {
    if git push; then
        sudo shutdown -h now
    fi
}

gitoff () {
    if git push; then
        sudo shutdown -h now
    else
        echo >&2 'git push failed, no shutdown'
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could wrap the command in a shell function, something like:

```
function gitpushoff() {
    if git push origin            # if this command succeeds, shutdown
    then
        sudo shutdown -h now
    else
        echo "git push failed: exit code [$?] Aborting shutdown..."
    fi
}
```